# Iterating through async task to update user role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am writing an Edit method for my C.R.U.D application but I am stuck with updating user role. I am trying to iterate through user roles and assign user role is not already assigned role. I get an error saying,`foreach cannot operate on variables of type 'Task<IList<string>>' because  'Task<IList<string>>' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'` How can I fix this ? OR What is a better way to approach this?

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult>  Edit(EditUserViewModel editUserViewModel)
        {
            var user = _userManager.Users.Where(e => e.Id == editUserViewModel.id).SingleOrDefault();

            user.FirstName = editUserViewModel.FirstName;
            user.LastName = editUserViewModel.LastName;
            user.MiddleName = editUserViewModel.MiddleName;
            user.Dob = editUserViewModel.Dob;

            var AllUserRoles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

            foreach(var userRole in AllUserRoles)
            {
                if (userRole != editUserViewModel.RoleToBeAssigned)
                {
                    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, editUserViewModel.RoleToBeAssigned);    
                }
            }

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            return View(user);

       }
```

Comment: Try  var AllUserRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);

Comment: Yes. You must `await` the call to get the roles in order to unwrap the task.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetRolesAsync` returns a `Task` that represents the asynchronous operation, containing a list of role names. So you can't directly iterate on that using a `foreach`. You should use the `await` keyword to wait the result and than iterate. Example: `var AllUserRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);`

You can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getrolesasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2) the `GetRolesAsync` method details.